# Outputting null

Tags: java, list, linked-list

I'm having a problem in which the method outputs null instead of returning the (n+1)th item of the list. Is there anything that I'm overlooking .

```
    public static ListElement getItem(ListElement head, int n){
    if(n == 0){                 
        return head;

    }else if(head == null){

            return null;
    }else{                      

        return  getItem(head.getNext(),n+1);

    }

}
```

Comment: From your recursive code I'd guess you want `getItem(head.getNext(),n-1);` instead of `getItem(head.getNext(),n+1);`

Comment: Why don't you write a while loop?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This code doesn't make sense. If head is not null, it will call `getItem(head.getNext(), n+1)` but eventually, `head` will equal `null` (and `n` will never go to 0) and therefore it will return you `null`.  Maybe you meant

`return getItem(head.getNext(), n-1)`.

Answer (score 0):

change from n+1 to n-1 (in order to get to the base case of the recursion, n == 0):

```
return  getItem(head.getNext(),n-1);
```

Answer (score 0):

You should be doing n-1, not n+1. n corresponds to the position of the element you want, and if you remove the top item in the list everything moves up down one position, not up.

Change to `getItem(head.getNext(),n-1);`